# ¿Existe alguna forma adaptada de la voz inglesa "millennial" en español?

Tags: traducción, solicitud-de-término, inglés, neologismos

Se usa mucho ultimamente la voz inglesa *millennial*, con un significado que he visto definido como:

- Aquellos nacidos en las dos últimas décadas del siglo XX. ([RAE en Twitter](https://twitter.com/RAEinforma/status/927830839681052673))
- Aquellos que no han conocido un mundo sin Internet. (walen en [La tertulia](https://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/message/50652058#50652058))
- Aquellos que han alcanzado la mayoría de edad a principios del siglo XXI. ([Oxford](https://www.lexico.com/en/definition/millennial))
- Aquellos nacidos en las décadas de 1980, 1990, o a principios de la década de 2000. ([Cambridge](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/es/diccionario/ingles/millennial))

Sin embargo, la voz no deja de ser un anglicismo. ¿Hay alguna adaptación al español?

Answer (score 2):

Sí. La propia RAE ha dejado claro en Twitter en multitud de ocasiones que la adaptación debería ser ***milenial*** (voz aguda). [Ejemplo](https://twitter.com/RAEinforma/status/1100008253289889793):

> Aunque no figure aún en el diccionario académico por ser neologismo reciente, como equivalente del anglicismo «millennial» puede usar en español la forma «milenial» [mileniál] (der. de «milenio», con suf. «-al»), plural «mileniales».

Añade en [otro tuit](https://twitter.com/RAEinforma/status/1088771729097478145):

> Esta forma permite un plural «mileniales», mejor acomodado a las pautas prosódicas y morfológicas de nuestra lengua.

Y en [otro tuit](https://twitter.com/RAEinforma/status/857222965783666690) incluso dan más opciones:

> «Millennial» se adapta como «milenial» o se traduce por «milénico». También se emplea «generación Y».

Personalmente, la voz ***milénico*** es la que más me gusta. :-)

Más información: *[Generación Y](https://es.wikipedia.org/wiki/Generaci%C3%B3n_Y)*.